# JavaScript onclick grammatically does not always work

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to set a `<td>` `onclick` event handler.
For some reason this works:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {
            var td = document.getElementById("td");
            var table = document.createElement("table");
            var row = table.insertRow(0);
            var cell = row.insertCell(0);
            cell.innerHTML = "test";
            cell.onclick = function () { alert(); };
            td.appendChild(table);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body id="td" onload="init()">
</body>
</html>
```

and when putting it in outside js file it doesn't work:

```
function buildChessBoard() {
    var currentColor = white;
    //var table = "<table>";
    var table = document.createElement("table");          
    for (var i = 0; i < chessBoardsize / 8; i++) {
        //table += "<tr>";
        var row = table.insertRow(i);
        for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            //table += "<td class=" + currentColor + "Cell" + " id=" + (i * 8 + j) + " onclick=setCell(this)></td>";
            var cell = row.insertCell(j);
            cell.innerHTML = "test";
            cell.onclick = function () { alert(); };
            if (j != 7) {
                if (currentColor == white)
                    currentColor = gray;
                else
                    currentColor = white;
            }
        }
        //table += "</tr>";
    }
    //table += "</table>";
    //chessBoardDiv.innerHTML = table;
    chessBoardDiv.appendChild(table);
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: js loaded before dom is ready, move it to bottom

Comment: both are added at same time.. in the body onload event

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/8ncqC/1/ (assuming all the variables are declared).

Comment: Are `white`, `chessBoardsize` and `gray` defined before use? Also FF will throw an error about an empty `alert()`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kLfpP/ you have syntax errors

Comment: yes they are... and in the working case it alerted with undefined..

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? As we've seen fiddles above, everything is fine, clicking cells alerts...

Comment: in the first example it does, in the second - it doesn't alert...

Comment: Then your code fails somewhere else, the second snippet you posted works fine (except in FF). Maybe you've more code in the original one?

Comment: i've only changed the HTML as you can see in the "//" to added the table programticly

Comment: Again, this snippet works (except in Firefox). What you see in the console? Any errors?

Comment: @AsafNevo: Please show us how you include that js file, and how you call the `buildChessBoard` function - there are a few undefined variables, most prominently `chessBoardDiv`

Comment: @Bergi I suppose OP can see the table, since in a comment above he says "`it doesn't alert`".